# How to make a simple 3D Ifc Viewer in WPF with Xbim v2

Tags: xbim

I am trying to make a small 3d viewer in VS2019 - are there any tutorials on XBim I have searched and cant find anything, I have seen this post [How to make a simple 3D Ifc Viewer in WPF with Xbim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952927/how-to-make-a-simple-3d-ifc-viewer-in-wpf-with-xbim) I need a turorial as I have put the refrences for xbim into my VS but how to add control to the wpf form and load my new house from a folder. I just need the link please Thank you for assisting

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to reuse components from [XbimWindowsUI project](https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimWindowsUI/tree/master/Xbim.Presentation). All components are available as [a nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xbim.WindowsUI). Once you add the package, you can follow the SO answer you [link in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952927/how-to-make-a-simple-3d-ifc-viewer-in-wpf-with-xbim).

For reference:

```xml
<xbim:DrawingControl3D
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    x:Name="DrawingControl"
    SelectedEntity="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=MainWindow, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Model="{Binding}"
    Focusable="True"
    MouseMove="DrawingControl_MouseMove">
    <xbim:DrawingControl3D.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#D1CBC4" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#C8FCFF"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </xbim:DrawingControl3D.Background>
</xbim:DrawingControl3D>
```

```cs
IfcStore ifcModel = IfcStore.Open("ifcFile.ifc");

var context = new Xbim3DModelContext(ifcModel);
context.CreateContext();

DrawingControl.Model = ifcModel;
DrawingControl.LoadGeometry(ifcModel);
```